# Run sbt plugin multiple times with different arguments

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a sbt project which uses a plugin. The plugin executes the following code (example, the real plugin is more complex):

```scala
val pluginTask = TaskKey[Unit]("pluginTask")
val pluginKey = SettingKey[Int]("pluingKey")
pluginTask <<= pluginKey map {i => println(i)} // real plugin does some IO operations
```

So I can set the `pluginKey` in my build.sbt and then execute `sbt pluginTask`. Because the plugin is complex I don't want to change the internal code. Now I want to make the plugin depending on a list of numbers, so it executes one time per list entry. The list can be set via build.sbt, because it's not changing at runtime. Is this possible without using the shell and execute sbt several times?